# Selenium Python cannot get elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, getelementsbyclassname

Here is the HTML code:

```
<i>
    <div id="Calendar">
    <div class="Title">booking</div>
    <div class="calendarHolder">
        <div class="month">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <span class="monthName">APRIL 2018</span>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="dayHolder">
        <div class="day holiday"><div class="dCell">SUN</div></div>
        <div class="day"><div class="dCell">MON</div></div>
        <div class="day"><div class="dCell">TUE</div></div>
        <div class="day"><div class="dCell">WED</div></div>
        <div class="day"><div class="dCell">THU</div></div>
        <div class="day"><div class="dCell">FRI</div></div>
        <div class="day last"><div class="dCell">SAT</div></div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>                       
    </div>
    <div class="dateHolder">
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">1</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">2</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">3</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">4</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">5</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">6</div></div>
        <div class="date last"><div class="dCell">7</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">8</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">9</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">10</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">11</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">12</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">13</div></div>
        <div class="date last"><div class="dCell">14</div></div>
        <div class="date time_day stin"><div class="dCell">15</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="5000">
    </div>
    <div class="date"><div class="dCell">16</div></div>

    </div>
</i>
```

There is a calendar which I need to click on an available date to perform further actions.

What I actually need is to click on the one with the class name "date time_day stin".

I have simply try the exact Xpath and also the following but it return error:
**No such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"class name","selector":"date.time_night.stin"}**

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('date.time_day.stin').click()
```

It return the same error by:

Dates = 
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#date.time_day.stin>div").text
    print (Dates)

Then I have tried different things of whether can I get the text of each div to find out what's the problem.

The only things I can get among all the find_element(s) trial are texts "SUN" to "SAT" with Class name "dCell" by:

```
lst = []
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#startBookingBlock div.dCell")
for i in calendar:
    lst.append(i.text)
print (lst)
```

But it still didn't return the others dates by the same class names, so.

I revamp it as the following and it returns "[]":

```
lst = []
calendar = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#dateHolder div.dCell")
for i in calendar:
    lst.append(i.text)
print (lst)
```

Then I tried to write more specifically as follow:

```
calendar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='startBookingBlock' and @class='dateHolder' and @class='date' and  @class='dCell']")
print (calendar)
```

However, it still prints "[]".

It can't seem to get anything under the "dateHolder" class but I just cannot figure out why would this happen, can anyone suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to share the URL?

Comment: Let me know about results after checking my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML code is broken -- it's missing one `</input>` after the input tag and two `</div>`s at the end.

Try running your code on this one (I just added those three):

```
<div id="Calendar">
  <div class="Title">booking</div>
  <div class="calendarHolder">
    <div class="month">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <span class="monthName">APRIL 2018</span>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
   <div class="dayHolder">
       <div class="day holiday"><div class="dCell">SUN</div></div>
       <div class="day"><div class="dCell">MON</div></div>
       <div class="day"><div class="dCell">TUE</div></div>
       <div class="day"><div class="dCell">WED</div></div>
       <div class="day"><div class="dCell">THU</div></div>
       <div class="day"><div class="dCell">FRI</div></div>
       <div class="day last"><div class="dCell">SAT</div></div>
       <div class="clearboth"></div>                       
   </div>
   <div class="dateHolder">
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">1</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">2</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">3</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">4</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">5</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">6</div></div>
        <div class="date last"><div class="dCell">7</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">8</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">9</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">10</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">11</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">12</div></div>
        <div class="date"><div class="dCell">13</div></div>
        <div class="date last"><div class="dCell">14</div></div>
        <div class="date time_day stin"><div class="dCell">15</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="5000"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="date"><div class="dCell">16</div></div>

  </div></div></div>
```

The XML that works for me (in an [online XPath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)) is as follows:

`div[@id="Calendar"]/div[@class="calendarHolder"]/div[@class="dateHolder"]/div[@class="date time_day stin"]`

Does this give the element you want?

Comment: thanks for your advise= ) I try it and it still return null 

I found the problem is even if the HTML code is correct, but I cannot retrieve the text inside div by class name / xpath which actually exist.

so i am wondering am I write the condition or expression wrong